# Unable to upgrade to PHP 5.4 on my VPS

Tags: debian, vps, php5

I'm able to see in phpinfo.php that I've PHP5.4 installed for use. Now, I'm trying to install symfony2 via composer. When I begin installing composer, it gives me an error stating that php5.3 is required but php5.2 is installed. It tells me to upgrade which I did yet I couldn't see any change. 
I'm checking the PHP version through ssh by php -v and it shows PHP5.2 installed. My simple question is, how can I upgrade this PHP version so that I can install the composer?
It's a Debian based Linux OS.

UPDATE:
A little more information. I added the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list to install PHP54.

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
```

I checked the Debian version by "cat /proc/version" and it is 4.4.5-8.

Comment: when you done the upgrade did you stop and start apache, etc after the install was done. this could be the problem.

Comment: Yes I did that several times. Do you know where is this php installed whose version is shown by "php -v" from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have libapache2-mod-php5 5.4 (used by the phpinfo page) installed, but have left php5-cli (php -V uses that) on 5.2.

Comment: And how would you suggest I upgrade it?

Comment: Same way as you would update any other package...

Comment: I did that. It says php-cli is already the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't get to upgrade the php version, I followed another way to get it done.
Taking inspiration from this article [here](http://www.tohir.co.za/category/software-and-technology/linux/), I managed to installand use composer.